# How to export mail folders using dovecot

Tags: imap, dovecot

I have an IMAP mailaccount, whereby the IMAP server is dovecot 2.0. Now I want to synchronize only some of the folders in my account. Some mail clients (e.g., Mac Mail) do not support selecting folders for synchronization: take all or nothing. Now I would like to know, whether I can use dovecot functionality to move particular folders out of my maildir and store them somewhere else (archiving). As soon as I have moved the folders out of my maildir, they are not synced by my Mail client.

Comment: It is probable that dovecot is secured against accessing files outside of Maildir.  But why would you use dovecot for this - you can move them from the command line: `mv /home/strauberry/Maildir/.folder /home/strauberry/Maildir.archive/`

Comment: When I do so, do I disturb dovecot indexing etc.? That's the reason why I thought of using dovecot functionality...

Comment: I haven't found it to be the case, dovecot should be able to deal with filesystem changes to its folders without complaint.

Answer (score 2):

You can download [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/)to achieve this IIRC. At least you can archive directory onto another remote imap account.